# Issue with `coldfusion.sql.QueryTable` (ColdFusion 10) and Java

Tags: java, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

After upgrading to **ColdFusion 10**, we are facing an issue with Java objects passed from ColdFusion to Java and vice versa.

We have one functions `myfunctionname()` in Java, which receives one parameter of type `coldfusion.sql.QueryTable`.
Now if I call this Java function from my ColdFusion code with a `cfquery` variable as parameter, either :

- there are no methods with the specified method name and argument types
- the `myfunctionname()`  method is overloaded with argument types that ColdFusion cannot decipher reliably
- ColdFusion found 0 methods that match the provided arguments. If this is a Java object and you verified that the method exists, use the `JavaCast()` function to reduce ambiguity

Also at some other places I am getting this errors :

```
Cannot convert coldfusion.sql.QueryTable to coldfusion.sql.QueryTable
Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

All these functions were working fine in **ColdFusion 8**.

Comment: (Edit) *All these functions were working fine in ColdFusion 8* Well I believe that class is undocumented, so it is always possible something changed... Just a guess but the "cannot convert class `xxx` to `xxx`..." could indicate a class loader problem. Any custom class loaders involved in your app? Hard to say more without seeing some code ...